# Modules with no regular elements in his annihilator

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Suppose $R$ is noetherian, suppose $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module of grade 0. This means that there are no regular elements in his annihilator. Does this implies that $\mathrm{dim}\;R/\mathrm{Ann}\;M=\mathrm{dim}\;R$? if not what can I say about the dimension of $M$?

Comment: Of course the equality is wrong! Take $(R,m)$ local and not CM of dimension $1$ and $M=R/m$.

Comment: yeah, I thought about it tonight and I came with the same example... there is something in general that we can say about the dimension of $M$?